# My custom git subcommands have stopped working

Tags: git, bash

I have a few custom git subcommands in my `~/bin` directory.  They are simple bash scripts named like `git-foobar` and they used to work, e.g. `git foobar`.  (The `~/bin` directory is on my PATH.)

I recently noticed they had stopped working and I can't figure out why.  The scripts themselves haven't changed.  However my PATH has...

A while ago I prepended `.git/safe/../../bin` to my PATH.  The idea is to make it easier to run a project's executables living in the project's `./bin` directory, i.e. so you can type `deploy` instead of `bin/deploy`.  For safety only "known safe" projects have their `bin` directory on the PATH, and projects are identified as safe by touching a `safe` file in the `.git` directory.  Everywhere else of course the location the prefix points to doesn't exist.

With the prefix, running a subcommand (e.g. `git foobar`) results in `git: 'foobar' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`  The script itself can be found on the PATH because `git-foob<tab>` autocompletes to `git-foobar` and runs; but git does not see it as a subcommand.

When I remove this prefix my git subcommands work again...although git's autocompletion doesn't (I *think* it used to for my custom subcommands).  I.e. typing `git foob<tab>` doesn't autocomplete to `git foobar`.

It seems that the `.git/safe/../../bin` PATH prefix is breaking the way git searches for subcommands, as well as git's autocompletion.

Can anyone explain what's going on?  And how I can get things working again?

Comment: `.git/safe/../../bin` goes outside of the current .git folder is it ok?

Comment: It specifies a `bin` directory when it is a sibling of a `.git` directory.  Not sure what you mean by is it ok?

Comment: strangely, I can't reproduce it on my comp, i created `git-lss` in `~/bin`, then prepended `.git/safe/../../bin`  to `PATH` and i'm able to call `git lss`

Comment: please show your prepended PATH

Comment: `.git/safe/../../bin:/Users/andy/.rbenv/shims:/Users/andy/.rbenv/bin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin` - perhaps my PATH isn't the problem. Hmm.

Comment: perhaps =) is that a ruby project?

Comment: and one yet question, I have no `safe` folder in my git, have you one? in each of your git projects? and which version of bash do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be using a tilde.  When I replace `~/bin` with `/Users/andy/bin` everything works properly again.

(This certainly used to work.  I wonder whether Apple's update to bash in response to shellshock affected tilde expansion in PATH.)

Comment: Changing the tilde to a full path fixed the "unable to find remote helper" error I was getting with git-remote-hg.